# How to return promise result from Vuex action instead of the promise itself?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an action in my vuex store:

```
export const actions = {
  myaction() {
    return 'foo'
  }
}
```

Can I get the promise result (here `foo`) in the `mounted()` life cycle hook and display it in the console ? If yes, how ?

I tried this:

```
mounted() {
  console.log(
    this.$store
      .dispatch('myaction')
      .then(res => res)
  )
}
```

But it returns the promise instead of the promise result I'm expecting.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you're looking for but wouldn't `.then(res => console.log(res))` do the trick?

Comment: @nikoshr I could even do `this.$store.dispatch('myaction').then(console.log)` to get `foo` in the console, but actually, what I need is to return `foo` either in the console or in a variable like `let myvar = this.$store.dispatch('myaction')`, but this returns the promise while I want the result in `myvar`

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't as it violates the uni-directional data flow paradigm.  Your goal should be to perform an action, set some data, and use a getter to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Either of these should work:

Using `.then()`:

```js
mounted() {
  this.$store
    .dispatch('myaction')
    .then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

Or if you're using ES2017 or later (or some compatibility tool like Babel), then you can use `async`/ `await`:

```js
async mounted() {
   const res = await this.$store.dispatch('myaction');
   console.log(res);
}
```

As @Dan mentions below, whilst this will return you the value of the Promise, this is not the intended usage of Vuex, which prefers all data to be saved to and accessed from Vuex's `state`.

It would be better to mutate the store in your action to save the value and then use a computed property in your component to retrieve it from state, either directly or through a getter. This can be done very cleanly with the [`mapGetters` Vuex helper function](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper).

Comment: This is an anti-pattern, you shouldn't be concerned with the return value from actions. Use state/getters instead.

Comment: Agreed, I misunderstood what OP was asking, I thought it was a confirmation that the promise that finished rather than returning a value to use in the component. Even then, as you say, getters should be used.